# How to make 1 block javascript experiment into 2 blocks that presents data at the end of the 2nd block and then save data to a local sever using MAMP

Tags: javascript, css, html

My goal for this experiment is to have 2 blocks of trials, both which flash 10 words and then the participants have to click yes or no if they saw the word or not (answer yes or no to 20 words).  After the 2 blocks I would like the data to be displayed and the experiment to end, although right now the experiment is infinite and displays data after every block.  I also need to know how to save the data with a "Save Data" button after presenting both of the blocks data at the end.  Any and all help appreciated!

If anyone has any ideas about how to create two blocks, as I have tried to initiate by declaring blocks = 0 at the beginning it would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="342.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    let index = 0, blocks=0;
    let words = ["fox", "tree", "wheel", "pillow", "target", "wool", "bread", "sport", "dog", "straw", "state",
              "mountain", "cot" , "green" , "napkin" , "grape" , "glass" , "drum" , "grass",];
    let stimuli = [];
    let N = words.length/2;
    let t;
    window.onload = initialize;

    function initialize() {
        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            stimuli.push(new Stimulus(words[i]));
        }
        shuffle(stimuli);
        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (i < N) {
                stimuli[i].presented = "1";
                stimuli[i].presOrder = i;
            }
            else {
                stimuli[i].presented = "0";
                stimuli[i].presOrder = "-1"
            }

        }

    }

    function Stimulus(word) {
        this.word = word;

    }

    Stimulus.prototype.toString = function () {

        return "\t Order Presented: " + this.presOrder + "\t Order tested: " + this.testOrder + "\t Word Presented:" + this.word + "\t  Response (0 or 1):"
            + this.resp + " \t Presented (0 or 1):" + this.presented;
    };


    function begin() {
        document.getElementById("b").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = "";
        t = setInterval(nextWord, 250)


    }

    function nextWordTest() {

        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = stimuli[index].word;
        stimuli[index].testOrder = index;

        if (blocks=1)
        {
            document.getElementById("b2").style.visibility = "visible";

        }

    }
function nextWord()
    {
        if (index < N)
        {
            document.getElementById("word").innerHTML =   stimuli[index].word;
            stimuli[index].presOrder = index;
            index++;
        }

        else
            {

            clearInterval(t);
            document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = "Click yes if you saw the word and " +
                "no if you did not see the word";
            document.getElementById("yes").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("no").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("b2").style.visibility = "hidden";
            index = 0;
            N = words.length;
            stimuli = shuffle(stimuli);

            nextWordTest();

        }


    }

    function record(resp) {
        stimuli[index].resp = resp;
        index++;
        if (index < N) {
            nextWordTest();
        }

        else {
            if (blocks===0){
                nextWordTest()
            }
            if (blocks===1)
            {
                document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = "finished";
                data = "";
                for (let i = 0; i < stimuli.length; i++)
                {
                    data += stimuli[i] + "\n";
                }
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("word").innerText = data;
            }

        }

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Attentional Blink Experiment </h1>


<p id="word">Push button to begin.</p>
<button type="button" id="yes" onclick="record(1)" style="visibility:    hidden">yes</button>
<button type="button" id="no" onclick="record(0)" style="visibility:   hidden">no</button>

<button type="button" id="b" onclick="begin()">Begin</button>
<button type="button" id="b2" onclick="begin()" style="visibility:  hidden">Continue</button>


</body>
</html>
```